# mongodb not importing json as expected

Tags: json, mongodb

I've been trying to import a json with this

`mongoimport --upsert --db mydb --jsonArray --file AllCards.json`

but what I get is

> "imported 0 objects"

I get a db with 0 elements.

The same JSON file is properly read when i load it with a JSON viewer.

This is part of the error message i get

> exception: Invalid JSON passed to mongoimport: code FailedtoParse: >FailedtoParse: Excpecting '{': offset:0 of :

The JSON file I'm trying to import has 6MB, but I have been trimming it to try to find the problem. The problem persists even with this content:

```
{
  "Air Elemental": {
    "layout": "normal",
    "name": "Air Elemental",
    "manaCost": "{3}{U}{U}",
    "cmc": 5,
    "colors": ["Blue"],
    "type": "Creature — Elemental",
    "types": ["Creature"],
    "subtypes": ["Elemental"],
    "text": "Flying",
    "power": "4",
    "toughness": "4",
    "imageName": "air elemental",
    "colorIdentity": ["U"]
  },
  "Ancestral Recall": {
    "layout": "normal",
    "name": "Ancestral Recall",
    "manaCost": "{U}",
    "cmc": 1,
    "colors": ["Blue"],
    "type": "Instant",
    "types": ["Instant"],
    "text": "Target player draws three cards.",
    "mciNumber": "1",
    "imageName": "ancestral recall",
    "colorIdentity": ["U"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check my answer and see if it works in your end? @David

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the JSON file you've included in your question. I've validated it using this tool: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ (take note for the future, it's useful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing it `mongoimport --upsert --db jason --collection contacts --file omuk.json`
And it is working fine. 
Found it:

```
2016-04-05T14:34:19.305+0600    connected to: localhost
2016-04-05T14:34:19.314+0600    imported 1 document
```

Comment: hey there!
It isn't working this way either. However there is a error message i have been getting: 2016-04-05T20:29:29.335-0300 Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files

I searched for that hotfix and installed and restarted the computer, but nothing changed.
I don't know if this has to do with the problem i'm having, specially because i did manage to load the other .json file as i mentioned on the original post.

I also tried the other response's solution but it didn't help at all

Comment: I have tried to remove the curly braces on both ends of the .json document. it didn't really help.
i have tried to replace db.<name>.count() with db.getCollection(<collection_name>).count() and it didn't really help.
one other thing i have tried is this db.getCollection(<collection_name>).findOne(). That will cause him to print the entire content of the 6MB json file. @jason-bourne

Answer (score 1):

The jsonArray option requires that the input be an array of JSON documents, ie the top level object in the file is an array. This isn't the case for your input.

If you just want one JSON document per line then (with current mongodb versions) that is the default mongoinport format - you don't need to pass any options to request it. Remove the `--jsonArray` and you should be ok.