# Mongoimport json files

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

In Ubuntu I have several folders with json files, which I try to import into mongo database. Why I am in a particular folder I try:

```
ls -1 *.json | while read jsonfile; 
do mongoimport --db mydb --collection logs --file $jsonfile --jsonArray --type json; 
done
```

But I get an error:

```
Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format -
found no opening bracket '[' in input source
```

Any ideas how I could do such an import where json files are not enclosed in `[]`? Also if someone knows how to loop over all maps (that contains json files) in a parent map, it would be appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: I'd suggest to post sample JSON file content for better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was `--jsonArray` option. I removed it and it worked. See [mongodb not importing json as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420242/mongodb-not-importing-json-as-expected)